# SSRS change fill color based on column values and parameters

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I want to change the background fill color of a column based on what parameters the user selects, and the values resulting from the filter are either red, green, or yellow.

If Parameter1 = "A" and Parameter2 = "B", then results are filled based on requirements (below). If Parameter1 = "C" and Parameter2 = "D", then numbers are filled based on other requirements. If Parameter1 and Parameter2 are any other value (E, F, G), then leave the background "White".

What I tried so far:

`=Switch(Parameters!Site.Value="A" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "B", IIF(Fields!Cost.Value < 100, "Green", IIF(Fields!Cost.Value >= 101 AND Fields!Cost.Value <= 200, "Yellow", IIF(Fields!Cost.Value > 300, "Red", "White"))), "White")
OR
(Parameters!Site.Value="C" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "D", IIF(Fields!Cost.Value < 300, "Green", IIF(Fields!Cost.Value >= 301 AND Fields!Cost.Value <= 400, "Yellow", IIF(Fields!Cost.Value > 400, "Red", "White"))), "White"), True, "White")`

Comment: seeing that you are likely using SQL Server for your dataset.. why don't you do this logic in SQL and return the color as a column... and then use that column for the background color rather than this convoluted iff statement at the reporting level..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use OR instead of AND like:

```
=Switch((Parameters!Site.Value="A" OR Parameters!Place.Value = "B") AND Fields!Cost.Value < 100, "Green",
(Parameters!Site.Value="A" OR Parameters!Place.Value = "B") AND Fields!Cost.Value >= 101 AND Fields!Cost.Value <= 200, "Yellow",
(Parameters!Site.Value="A" OR Parameters!Place.Value = "B") AND Fields!Cost.Value > 300, "Red", "White")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following expression:

```
=Switch(
Parameters!Site.Value="A" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "B" AND Fields!Cost.Value < 100, "Green",
Parameters!Site.Value="A" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "B" AND Fields!Cost.Value <= 200, "Yellow",
Parameters!Site.Value="A" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "B" AND Fields!Cost.Value > 300, "Red",
Parameters!Site.Value="C" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "D" AND Fields!Cost.Value < 300, "Green",
Parameters!Site.Value="C" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "D" AND Fields!Cost.Value >= 301 AND Fields!Cost.Value <= 400, "Yellow",
Parameters!Site.Value="C" AND Parameters!Place.Value = "D" AND Fields!Cost.Value > 400, "Red",
True, "White"
)
```

Comment: For some reason this didn't work.. do you possibly know any workarounds for this?

Comment: Give me some sample values for which the expression doesn't work and what should be the right color in each case. Even better, update your question with a table of conditions and expected color output